# Preference is not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, overrides, preference

I am trying to override ErrorHandler class using preference but it is not working. 
**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler" type="Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model\ErrorHandler"/>

</config>
```

**ErrorHandler.php**

```
<?php
namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model;

class ErrorHandler extends \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler{
    public function getHandler()
    { echo"hii"; exit;
        if (strpos($errorStr, 'DateTimeZone::__construct') !== false) {
            // there's no way to distinguish between caught system exceptions and warnings
            return false;
        }

        $errorNo = $errorNo & error_reporting();
        if ($errorNo == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $msg = isset($this->errorPhrases[$errorNo]) ? $this->errorPhrases[$errorNo] : "Unknown error ({$errorNo})";
        $msg .= ": {$errorStr} in {$errorFile} on line {$errorLine}";
        throw new \Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

I used echo exit to check preference is working or not. When any error or exception comes it doesn't echo and exit. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing same issue

Comment: There is no method `getHandler` in that class.

Comment: Same issue faced, is there any solution for it...?

Answer (score 1):

class name was wrong, you mentioned `Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model\Errors` so it should be

```
<?php
namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model;

class Errors extends \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler{
    .....................
    .....................
    .....................
    .....................
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake but it is not working still.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that someone else has already preferenced the targeted class:-

```
find vendor/ -name "di.xml" -exec egrep "ErrorHandler" {}  \;
```

and try to scan your custom code folder:

```
find app/code -name "di.xml" -exec egrep "ErrorHandler" {}  \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar kind of problem, as the preference was not working.

While debugging I found there were some `private` properties in the original class file.

Then I added all those `private` properties as `protected` into the preferenced/over-rided file and then it worked.

---

Maybe this can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

**di.xml**,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler" type="Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model\Errors"/>

</config>
```

**You have to declare classname ErrorHandler instead of Errors**

```
 <?php
namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model;

class Errors extends \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler{
    protected $errorPhrases = [
        E_ERROR => 'Error',
        E_WARNING => 'Warning',
        E_PARSE => 'Parse Error',
        E_NOTICE => 'Notice',
        E_CORE_ERROR => 'Core Error',
        E_CORE_WARNING => 'Core Warning',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'Compile Error',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'Compile Warning',
        E_USER_ERROR => 'User Error',
        E_USER_WARNING => 'User Warning',
        E_USER_NOTICE => 'User Notice',
        E_STRICT => 'Strict Notice',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'Recoverable Error',
        E_DEPRECATED => 'Deprecated Functionality',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'User Deprecated Functionality',
    ];

    public function handler($errorNo, $errorStr, $errorFile, $errorLine)
    {   
        echo"hii"; exit;
        if (strpos($errorStr, 'DateTimeZone::__construct') !== false) {
            // there's no way to distinguish between caught system exceptions and warnings
            return false;
        }

        $errorNo = $errorNo & error_reporting();
        if ($errorNo == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $msg = isset($this->errorPhrases[$errorNo]) ? $this->errorPhrases[$errorNo] : "Unknown error ({$errorNo})";
        $msg .= ": {$errorStr} in {$errorFile} on line {$errorLine}";
        throw new \Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I try this out earlier that's why i changed class name to Errors.

Comment: any error are display?

Comment: I am generating an error to see is this working or not. Unfortunately it is not working. In my system.log it is saying that  "main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4f0430021afacc712191c816b7a55d6dd and handles default, hello_mvvm_hello_world: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []"

Comment: Although I have created a another plugin in same di.xml file and it is working file. I don't know what is the problem in this preference.

Comment: sorry i mean preference not plugin

Comment: you want to generate new method in this file?

Comment: No, I want to override method handler in ErrorHandler class.

Comment: yes you can try with above solutions, its work for you.

Comment: I think which i can do using getHandler() function. Am i right ?

Comment: yes you have to just give original function name not any prefix.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: It's not working @Rakesh.

Comment: Have you remove var folder and check? any log are generate?

Comment: yes i do that and in system.log file   " [2016-11-08 05:50:29] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4f0430021afacc712191c816b7a55d6dd and handles default, hello_mvvm_hello_world: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] [] "

Comment: hello_mvvm is frontname of module in routes.xml

Comment: Have you call this function in phtml file?

Comment: I generate a simple exception in phtml file for example i changed variable name $total to $totals. And it is showing undefined variable totals but it should print "hi" as i am using echo "hii" exit in handler function.

Comment: I Have many files override using Preference concept.
When i updating Magento version it will not update.
So what is the better way to update those code

Answer (score 0):

your preference in di.xml should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler" type="Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Model\ErrorHandler"/>

</config>
```

As you have declared your class name same.

Comment: Yes I did the same but not working still

Comment: remove  var/ data and pub/static data, and then apply 
static content deploy and reindex

Comment: Ok let me check..

Comment: It's not working @Ronak

Comment: how you have test?

Comment: I generate a simple exception in phtml file for example i changed variable name $total to $totals. And it is showing undefined variable totals but it should print "hi" as i am using echo "hii" exit in handler function.

Comment: Am i right @Ronak ?

Comment: just try to print hi at first line of your handler file. then check

Comment: Yes i am doing the same.

Comment: not at phtml file

Comment: Yes i echo out at top of handler file but it is not printing anything

Comment: But interesting thing is that i have created a new preference for Magento\Catalog\Model\Product and it is working fine.

Comment: out of class declaration?

Comment: yes, out of class declaration